# Cross validation dataset folds for Random Forest feature importance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to generate random forest's feature importance plot using cross validation folds. When only feature (X) and target(y) data is used, the implementation is straightforward such as:

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(X, y)
importances = pd.DataFrame({'FEATURE':data_x.columns,'IMPORTANCE':np.round(rfc.feature_importances_,3)})
importances = importances.sort_values('IMPORTANCE',ascending=False).set_index('FEATURE')

print(importances)
importances.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

which yields:
[image]

However, how could I transform this code in order to create a similar plot for every cross-validation folds (k-fold) that I would be creating ?

The code that I have at the moment is:

```
# Empty list storage to collect all results for displaying as plots
mylist = []

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=3)
for train, test in kf.split(X, y):
    train_data = np.array(X)[train]
    test_data = np.array(y)[test]
for rfc = RandomForestClassifier():
    rfc.fit(train_data, test_data)
```

For example, the above code creates (3 folds) using the Cross validation technique and my aim is to create feature importance plots for all the 3 folds, resulting in 3 feature importance plot graphs. At the moment, it's giving me loop errors.

I am not sure what would be the most efficient technique to use each of the created (k-folds) to generate feature importance graph via Random forest respectively, for each of the (k-folds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# classification dataset
data_x, data_y = make_classification(n_features=9)

# feature names must be declared outside the function
# feature_names = list(data_x.columns)

kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
count = 1
# test data is not needed for fitting
for train, _ in kf.split(data_x, data_y):
    rfc.fit(data_x[train, :], data_y[train])
    # sort the feature index by importance score in descending order
    importances_index_desc = np.argsort(rfc.feature_importances_)[::-1]
    feature_labels = [feature_names[-i] for i in importances_index_desc]

    # plot
    plt.figure()
    plt.bar(feature_labels, rfc.feature_importances_[importances_index_desc])
    plt.xticks(feature_labels, rotation='vertical')
    plt.ylabel('Importance')
    plt.xlabel('Features')
    plt.title('Fold {}'.format(count))
    count = count + 1
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One of the cause of the error is this code `rfc.fit(train_data, test_data)`. You should put train labels as 2nd argument, not test data.

As for the plotting, you can try to do something like code below. I assume you are aware that in this case k-folds CV is only used to select different sets of training data. The test data is ignored because there is no prediction made:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# dummy classification dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_features=10)
# dummy feature names
feature_names = ['F{}'.format(i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]

kf = KFold(n_splits=3)
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
count = 1
# test data is not needed for fitting
for train, _ in kf.split(X, y):
    rfc.fit(X[train, :], y[train])
    # sort the feature index by importance score in descending order
    importances_index_desc = np.argsort(rfc.feature_importances_)[::-1]
    feature_labels = [feature_names[i] for i in importances_index_desc]
    # plot
    plt.figure()
    plt.bar(feature_labels, rfc.feature_importances_[importances_index_desc])
    plt.xticks(feature_labels, rotation='vertical')
    plt.ylabel('Importance')
    plt.xlabel('Features')
    plt.title('Fold {}'.format(count))
    count = count + 1
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Dinesh you should not use edit suggestion to ask question or give feedback. You should add comment like this and/or update your question. As for your question, you should be able to get feature names from pandas df columns `feature_names = data_x.columns`

Comment: I tried referencing the column names using the code line you provided, however, I'm still not able to generate plots with respective feature names. I am observing the same "F" formatted plots. Could you please show me which areas in the previous code I should be placing these ?

Comment: You only need to change 1 line where the `feature_names` is declared. Assign it with list of feature names. Assuming you have a dataframe `data_x` with feature names as columns, you should replace the line with `feature_names = list(data_x)`

Comment: I have been able to solve the feature_names issue now, however I'm getting a new error in this form:

---> 20     feature_labels = [feature_names[i] for i in importances_index_desc]

IndexError: list index out of range.

I think if you could provide some help on how I can fix this line, the plot will definitely work.

Comment: I think you really need to work on your python basic. This error simply indicates that you list in `feature_names` that does not have same size as the number of features/columns of `X` (the dataset). If you still can't make this simple thing works, I'd suggest you post your complete code & dataset in the question because there is no easy way to tell what kind of bug you introduced